# Hidden content takes up height(isotope)

Tags: jquery, html, height, hide, jquery-isotope

I am using this gallery to display portfolio items on my website:
http://www.webdesigntunes.com/coding/jquery-filterable-portfolio/

It uses isotope-jquery to display the items so the `div` container that includes the portfolio images calculates the height based on the article classes that are within it:

```
<section class="main">

    <div class="portfolio">

        <article class="entry video">
            <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="http://vimeo.com/34266952">
            <img src="images/portfolio/work1.jpg" alt="">
            <span class="video-hover"></span>
            </a>
        </article>

        <article class="entry video">
            <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="http://vimeo.com/34266952">
            <img src="images/portfolio/work1.jpg" alt="">
            <span class="video-hover"></span>
            </a>
        </article>

    </div>

</section>
```

What I want to do is to hide some of them and add a `load more` button. So I renamed the ones I want to hide to "entry video hidden":

```
<article class="entry video hidden">
    <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="http://vimeo.com/34266952">
        <img src="images/portfolio/work1.jpg" alt="">
        <span class="video-hover"></span>
    </a>
</article>
```

Then using jquery I use `hide()` to make them disappear:

```
$("article.entry.video.hidden").hide();
```

Although they are hidden successfully, they still take up place on the container `div` so there is empty space showing up. I suppose this is how isotope automatically works, but is there any way to come around this?

Maybe there is a way to ignore the height of the article elements that are inside the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of trying to hide those elements, I gave them a new class name(.designs_hidden) and then used the isotope append to add them:

```
var $newItems = $(".designs_hidden");
$(".loadMore").click(function(){
$pfcontainer.isotope('appended', $newItems);
$pfcontainer.isotope({ filter: '.designs,.designs_hidden' });
return false;
});
```