# How to remove html comment using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, comments, hide

I am trying to remove html comments(`<!-- -->`) using jQuery and then use slide or show to make some `<article>` elements within a div to show up. The reason I am doing this instead of using .hide directly is because when I use .hide the height of the hidden `<article>`'s is still shown so the container div has empty space below.

Is that possible?

Comment: Uhm, no! When something is hidden it does not take up space. You've probably been using visibility, which does take up space. Do it with the display property, using comments is plain wrong and a hundred times harder to do.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I don't think comments go in the DOM, so you can't do it as you originally specified.

Comment: Actually, seems I'm wrong: http://www.bennadel.com/index.cfm?dax=blog:1563.view

Comment: @Barmar - They are part of the DOM, and even have a nodeType so they can be filtered, but you generally shouldn't have a need to ever work with them in javascript.

Comment: @adeneo Here's my other question on this, which I couldn't solve. That's why I am trying to find out another way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811354/hidden-content-takes-up-heightisotope

Comment: So what you really have is an issue with isotope making space for elements that you've hidden. Did you try running the line of jQuery that hides the elements before you run isotope on the container.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but didn't work. The space is still there. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [jquery uncomment plugin](http://chivil.com/uncomment/) you can remove

here is the library file

[library](http://chivil.com/uncomment/jquery.uncomment.js)

library code by Romuald Brunet

```
   (function($) {
    $.fn.uncomment = function(recurse) {
        $(this).contents().each(function() {
            if ( recurse && this.hasChildNodes() ) {
                $(this).uncomment(recurse);
            } else if ( this.nodeType == 8 ) {
                // Need to "evaluate" the HTML content,
                // otherwise simple text won't replace
                var e = $('<span>' + this.nodeValue + '</span>');
                $(this).replaceWith(e.contents());
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

example ---

```
 <p id="uncomment">
  The <!-- <em>quick</em> brown -->
  fox jumps over the <!-- lazy --> dog <br />
  <a href="#">Click here to reveal <!-- hidden --> comments</a>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#uncomment a:last').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#uncomment').uncomment(/* recurse */ true );
});
</script>
```